# Java app does not open on MacOS Sierra

Tags: java, macos, macos-sierra, .app

I developed a Java application and created .app package.

When I download from any website this .app (in .zip), App crashes in MacOS Sierra, but, if I execute JavaAppLauncher manually, inside .app contents, it's work perfect.

Or if I copy `.zip` in Local Network, `.app` works fine.

I Tried to use `spctl --master-disable` but doesn't help.

I don't know what's happening.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Have you checked security? OSX may be blocking it since it doesn't view it as a "secure" program. Try right clicking and opening the file from Finder.

Comment: Yes, I checked. I tried, it's show the Internet download message, I choose open and it doesn't work. I tried to use codesign too, and nothing work.